# Primefaces only get file to download on click

Tags: jsf, primefaces, download

I have a datatable with a commandLink in each row, to get a file from the database.

The code I have for the commandLink is:

```
<p:commandLink title="download file" styleClass="fa fa-lg fa-download output-button" actionListener="#{fileSearchPageBean.getFileToDownload(result.id)}">
    <p:fileDownload  value="#{fileSearchPageBean.file}"  />
</p:commandLink>
```

The function getFileToDownload in the page bean makes the query to get the file and puts it in the file variable, that is in the fileDownload.

What is happening is that when the datatable is loaded, it makes the queries to get all the files for all the rows. The thing is I just want to make the query and get a specific file when the link for that file is clicked, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The function i talk about (the one that get's the file from the DB) is the one in the actionListener of the commandLink (actionListener="#{fileSearchPageBean.getFileToDownload(result.id)}").

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't  understand what you mean.. 
The code for the provided is working and I cand download the file when pressing the image. The thing is, there is a datatable that has 10 lines and in each line a `p:commandLink` is present. When the page is loaded, the function in the action listener of the `p:commandLink` is called and I would like to prevent that.

Comment: Use ajax="false" in p:commandLink